# Monad transformers - random + error + log for board game service

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm currently trying to port a significantly sized project from Go to Haskell (board games by email service) as I've been having fun writing Haskell recently and find it models game logic quite well.

I've got a fairly clear idea of what I want to achieve having written the service and 25 games previously, but I'm not certain it's the best way to go about it or exactly how to implement it.

The majority of the exposed board game functions have the following:

- Randomness
- Errors (mainly validation, when doing things that would break game rules)
- Logging (a human readable log is produced when things happen in the game)

The monads I've been attempting to use are the following:

- [MonadRandom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.7/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#t:MonadRandom)
- [Either](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras-0.52.0/docs/Control-Monad-Either.html)
- [Writer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Writer.html)

My problem is that I'm struggling to figure out how I can use all three in a single function.  For a fairly contrived example, I define a type for the game data and pass that into and return it from a number of these function:

```
data Game = Game { rnd :: Int
                 , numPlayers :: Int
                 , deck :: [Int]
                 , hands :: [[Int]]
                 }

-- newGame takes a player count and returns a Game.  Needs randomness, errors and logging.
newGame :: Int -> ? Game

-- drawCard takes a player number and an existing Game and returns a Game.  Needs errors and logging.
drawCard :: Int -> Game -> ? Game
```

Actual implementations of these sorts of functions aren't an issue if they just return `Game` or use a single monad.  The moment I start needing to combine monads is when I start tripping over myself.

If anyone is able to provide an example of how you would combine monads for the two contrived functions I'd be hugely appreciative.  I think once I have a couple of examples I can jump this hurdle and keep learning as I go.

Comment: Have you tried writing the function, and letting it infer the type? Alternatively if you cannot do that, there is a fairly good explanation of `mtl` monad transformers [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) including examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use monad trasformers to make up a monad, that would provide a way to generate random numbers, hold state and other things you want to do.

Let's start with `MonadRandom`. The documentation says that `IO` is an instance of it, so we can use it as base monad:

```
newtype Game a = Game (IO a)
```

To make `Game` store and modify data let's make it a `MonadState` by wrapping it into `StateT`:

```
data GameState = GameState {
                 , numPlayers :: Int
                 , deck :: [Int]
                 , hands :: [[Int]]
                 }

newtype Game a = Game (StateT GameState (IO a))
```

In the same way you can teach `Game` to provide logging facilities via `WriterT`:

```
type LogType = String

newtype Game a = Game (WriterT LogType (StateT GameState (IO a)))
```